# Ошибка в запросе к БД PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

В лог-файле error.log пишется следующее PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса в конце\nLINE 1: ...LECT COUNT(id) FROM Questions  WHERE client_id=\n                                                                       ^ in /var/www/.../section5.php on line 5
Сам запрос работает:

```
$result_count = pg_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Questions WHERE client_id=".$client['id']."");
```

Почему возникает такая ошибка?

Comment: как видите после client_id= ничего нет, значит $client['id'] у вас пустая.

Comment: cделайте var_dump($client); и еще на всякий случай добавьте ; в конце запроса вот так $result_count = pg_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Questions WHERE client_id=".$client['id'].";"); в противном случае вторые кавычки лишние.

Comment: $client['id'] не может быть пустой, иначе запрос не выводил бы результат.

Comment: Вы просто сделайте var_dump($client); die; и в комментарии оставьте результат =) Так как судя по ошибке в запросе вместо значения, а возможно перед значением, у вас подставляется \n,  а \n - это символ переноса строки в unix

Comment: Помогло разрешить вопрос Ваш совет про var_dump(), так я узнала, что в запросе вместо числового типа данных указываю строковый, вот php на это и возмущался.